# Angular App using NodeJS: setting two home/index page inside same App for two different domains

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am planning to build a web application using Angular, NodeJS and MongoDB.
The main two views and theirs associated services and controllers are:

```
1. cats.html
   .... cats-ctrl.js
   .... cats-service.js
2. dogs.html
   .... dogs-ctrl.js
   .... dogs-service.js
```

Assume that I have two parked domains A.) **Dogs.com** and B.) **Cats.com**
So what I need is that If I want to set cats.html(cats.com/#/home)  as home page for cats.com  and dogs.html as home page for dogs.com(dogs.com/#/home) **without** having any extra url levels.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Can someone guide me on how to achieve it ?

Comment: Just have an `index` that redirects to one or the other.

Comment: @zurfyx : how can I redirects to specific page based on the domain call ?

Comment: you can check the `window.location.hostname` to find something like `stackoverflow.com`; see my reply

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unique index that redirect or hides / show based on the `hostname`.

```
window.location.hostname
```

You can execute your redirect with router.navigate

```
this.router.navigate(['route']);
```